# ¿Cómo implementar emails recordatorios?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo un proyecto en laravel con fullcalendar (un calendario de eventos) donde hay clientes que hacen reuniones con expertos, y tengo una simple integración de mailgun, que al crearse un evento se envía un mail al experto seleccionado avisando que tiene una nueva cita, pero no encuentro información sobre cómo enviar emails de manera recordatoria cuando queden 24 horas o menos al horario que el cliente selecciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso es probable que necesites un hacer un ["Cron"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_(Unix)). Me parece que Laravel tiene un [sistema integrado para ello](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling).

O también puedes usar algún sistema externo de "Task Scheduling"/["Planificador"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planificador). Puedes encontrar algunos a base Node.js y [Redis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) o MongoDB. Algunos de estos son [Bee](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue), [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) y [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda).

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Laravel tiene un "Task Scheduling" que utiliza cron, debes configurarlo antes de utilizarlo.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

Esto haria lo que necesitas, puedes generar una consulta que obtenga los usuarios a los cuales quieres enviar el correo *"(cuando queden 24 horas o menos al horario que el cliente selecciona)"* y ejecutar el envio de correos y la consulta cada determinado tiempo.